# What form of input does z3 smt solver take? How to use a file to read the equation required to be solved?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

```
from z3 import *
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
s = Solver()
try:
    f = open("read.txt","r")
    try:
        str = f.read()
        length = len(str)
        s.add(str)
    finally:
        f.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```

I wrote the above code but it is not working. It is not taking a string as an input, and I am unable to find what kind of input it accepts.

Comment: How does the content of `read.txt` look? Did you try to find out if you can load assertions in SMTLib2 format?

Comment: Try doing something like `eval('s.add({})'.format(str.strip()))`. BTW, `str` is the name of a built-in and shouldn't be used as the name of a variable.

Comment: read.txt contains an equation of the form x + y == 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can essentially do what was suggested by [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau). Keep in mind this is a big hack and insecure because the file `read.txt` may contain arbitrary Python commands. Anyway, the following piece of code, will evaluate each line of the input file, and add the resultant object into the solver `s`. If the file `read.txt` contains `x + y == 2`, then the output will be:

```
sat
[y = 0, x = 2]
```

Here is the updated code:

```py
from z3 import *
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
s = Solver()
try:
    f = open("read.txt","r")
    try:
        for l in f:
            s.add(eval(l))
    finally:
        f.close()
except IOError:
    pass
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

Another solution is to create files in SMT-LIB 2.0 format, and use the approach described in the following posts:

- [Z3 4.0 Z3_parse_smtlib2_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049918/z3-4-0-z3-parse-smtlib2-string/11050755#11050755)
- [Z3 with string expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805839/z3-with-string-expressions/10810676#10810676)